# Connecting my domain with Microsoft 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, dns, office365, domain

I currently have two domains registered with GoDaddy (domain.com and domain.ca), GSuite to handle emails for 20 users and a Microsoft Standard Business subscription. These two domain were added to Microsoft 365 backend but they're not connected. All users were setup using .ca domain
GSuite is using user@domain.com as its official email but users can only login on Microsoft services using user@domain.ca.  This is causing issues with Teams when people are sending meeting invites and calendar synchronization. This issue is expected since Microsoft is living on domain.ca and all email is happening with GSuite under domain.com

I have a workaround with this by setting up a redirection rule to each .ca mail box to .com. All users can see Teams invites that were sent to .ca being forwarded to their .com mail boxes but unfortunately RSVP doesn't work. GSuite doesn't know anything about .ca domain.

Being a *newbie* Microsoft 365 admin, I'm not sure if I should stablish a connection between domain.com and Microsoft 365 to fix this problem. Microsoft will automatically update all DNS entries to point to their service and I believe all users will lose access to their mail boxes. Moreover, I don't know if this will ever help me fixing this issue with calendar between Teams and GSuite.
Can anyone shed a light on how should I address this problem?

I understand this situation is very confusing and I'm not a IT expert with all this domain/email/microsoft/gsuite thing.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no perfect way to achieve your requirements. Calendar information is stored in mailbox, so your issue is about two mailbox accounts: GSuit mailbox and Exchange Online mailbox. They are from two different email systems, so they cannot work as you expected. You could refer to the workaround mentioned in this thread: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/teams-calendar-synchronization-with-google-calendar/m-p/1163000

Please note this reply:

[image]

Yes, I agree with: “So all-in-all my conclusion is that if you really want Teams to work smoothly then you're really going to have to bite the bullet and migrate to M365.” , I notice that you have verified two domains in one tenant, to migrate your mailboxes to M365 is the better option.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! After reading the whole thread that you have suggested I decided to migrate all to M365 eco system and I have another question. Do you know if it's possible to do this test with one or two users before migrate the whole company? I've been reading about MX entries on the DNS tables to connect our .com email with Microsoft. The idea is to connect our domain .com with microsoft and add MX entries so we will have the whole company still pointing to Gsuite and two users pointing to Exchange.

Comment: Glad to know my reply is helpful and you could mark it as answer.
For migration, you could refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/migrating-imap-mailboxes/migrate-g-suite-mailboxes, and please note  Step 2: Add users to Microsoft 365 or Office 365 --You can add your users either one at a time, or several users at a time. Do not proceed to Set up domain, until your Gmail mailboxes are migrated to Microsoft 365 or Office 365.